# How old is a chicken when it's time to be cooked?

Tags: chicken, meat

How old is a chicken usually allowed to grow before it's ready to be used for cooking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They can be as young as 8 weeks, and up to a year or more. The preferred cooking method changes with age. [Here is a handy chart](http://www.backyardpoultrymag.com/issues/5/5-4/seasonal_chickens.html) of the ages/weights/options.